# Conf call passcode repeats in skype application

Tags: skype

I installed Skype in my andriod mobile to place conf calls. When AV prompts for passcode, after dialling in passcode, the AV reads passcodes as if dialled multiple times. For example 12345#, AV reads out as 112223345# like that. What is going wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that dial pad in certain mobiles echoes very badly. Workaround was, when I dial in the access code, I have to put on mute. Only then it works. Surprise is, this works fine on other apps like viber, google call. Only skype dial pad is having this issue.